# asp.net gridview select radio button get row label value using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

when click on a_btn(this is out side of gridview) need to read value of selected grid view row label value. below code not taking single row value please give solution

```
$("#a_btn").click(function () {
    if(('table[id*="GridView_Customer"] input[type="radio"]:checked')) {
        var lblStatus = $('table[id*="GridView_Customer"] [id*="lblStatus"]').text();
        alert(lblStatus);
    }
});
```

Comment: provide us generated html .

Comment: <a id="a_btn">cancel</a> //Anchor tag <asp:gridview id="GridView_Customer" autogeneratecolumns="false" runat="server" > <Columns> <asp:TemplateField> <ItemTemplate> <asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="RadioButton_Select" AutoPostBack="True"> </asp:RadioButton> </ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField> <asp:TemplateField > <ItemTemplate> <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>' width="80px" runat="server"> </asp:Label> </ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField> </Coloumns> </asp:Gridview>when i select "RadioButton_Select" and click on "a_btn" need to get "lblStatus" value

Comment: why did you post the same question 20 minutes apart? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367512/how-to-get-selectedradio-button-row-valuelabel-in-gridview-using-jquery